# log4net compact framework 3.5 No app.config to add file appenders

Tags: c#, log4net

I am developing a log4net using CF 3.5 VS 2008 on windows mobile 6.

I have used log4net before in my windows xp applications, and I always put the configuration in the app.config file.

However, this is my first time using log4net with CF3.5. And I have noticed there is no app.config file, and when I try to add a new item there is no template for one. Am I missing something here?

If 3.5 doesn't have a app.config file. Where can I put my log4net configuration? I would like to log4net using the file appender and save the log in the directory where the application is executing from.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compact framework does not support app.config files but you can emulate such behavior.

Create a xml with setting and then read content of that file.

I found this workaround that work for me:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/dotnetcompactframework_app_config.asp

Answer (score 3):

This reaction is a bit late, and probably you have solved it already. 
However there might be some other users that have the same problem.

You can also specify that you want to use a different config-file using the XmlConfiguratorAttribute. See [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfiguratorAttribute.html).
For instance you could specify the log4net-configuration in 'log4net.config' which is in your bin-directory and add in the assemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="log4net.config",Watch=true)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruben, This won't work because `XmlConfiguratorAttribute` is not available from `log4net` to compact framework.

Instead, you can use `XmlConfigurator.Configure("filename.config")` replacing `filename.config` by the path to your log4net configuration file.

I've put this on the main program class of a Windows Application on my mobile application.

Hugs :)

Comment: @diogo-paschoal. Don't forget to call `LogManager.Shutdown()` before exiting your application. See [this](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html#Assembly_attributes).