# Best method of logging error codes

Tags: c#, vb.net, error-handling, compact-framework

I am trying to programmatically log error codes from any exceptions thrown on a PDA using CF3.5.  Does anyone know how to get the most precise code for an error?

I've been looking at getting the HResult value of the thrown exception (which I can do), but this doesn't seem specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

you can surely use Log4Net, it works in the CF 3.5, see this post where people were discussing how to configure it:

[log4net compact framework 3.5 No app.config to add file appenders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968437/log4net-compact-framework-3-5-no-app-config-to-add-file-appenders)

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to use any open source libraries on this project

Answer (score 0):

The [Power Toys for .NET Compact Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c8174c14-a27d-4148-bf01-86c2e0953eab&displaylang=en) contains Remote Logging Configuration Tool which I haven't used myself but it sounds like what you are looking for.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/Video/cc647002 for a How-To on configuring and reading the log files.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I'm trying to do this programmatically

Comment: Are you trying to catch any error in any application or any error in your own application? If your own then the thrown exceptions .ToString() gives a whole lot of juicy information. From the help file on Exception.ToString(): __The default implementation of ToString obtains the name of the class that threw the current exception, the message, the result of calling ToString on the inner exception. If any of these members is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic), its value is not included in the returned string.__